# Custom Report based on tags

Tags: rally

I am trying to generate a report based on tags, attached to user stories in Rally.I looked at the 2 options available in Rally.

1. Tagged Story Burndown
2. Custom report by setting filter as tag .But this gives only some predefined attributes like Count of work items marked with this tag.

I am looking for an exhaustive report based on tags.

Is there any other option available in Rally or do i have to generate an external app.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a built in chart, those might be it.  It'll all depend on what type of report you'd like to generate.

Some resources to build your own app are:

Rally 2.0rc1 API - http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/

Video Tutorials: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3PQ-IsMxhG1AXBMwOLfFyRas8kUIlrIi (they are in 2.0p5, but they'll get you close to the concept)